# How does Krita compare to Corel Painter?

Tags: software-recommendation, krita, corel-painter

I am new to painting and in the process of learning. I would like to know what advantages and disadvantages Krita and Corel Painter have. If you have used both of these Software and finished a painting using them, what are your positive and negative views on each Software?
I am only a beginner, so I cannot compare the two apart from preferring the Krita's user interface.

Comment: Get Krita for free, and Get Painter for a free 30 Day Trial. Before it looks ome tutorials to maximize the trial period.

Comment: My fav artists back in a day were all using Painter but I hated working in it so much: its quirkiness, brush settings overcomplexity — which was never an issue for others. Rafael is right: try them both and see what works _for you_

Comment: Also, why only Painter or Krita? No SAI, no Clip Studio Paint?

Comment: One big con of Corel Painter is that even very recent versions stop working with OS updates. As soon as the next year's version is out, Corel stops supporting the earlier versions, so you end up having to spend a lot of money -- sometimes yearly -- just to keep the software running even if you don't care about the new features. Just because they can't write software that doesn't break with each OS update, customers end up spending a lot of money. Something to keep in mind. (I've had it enough, and won't be updating anymore. Also there are lots of alternatives now.)

Answer (score 3):

I am more familiar with *Corel Painter* than with *Krita*, but I will give it a shot

### Expense

This is an obvious one for a lot of people. *Corel Painter Essentials* costs about $40 minimum. Getting the latest annual version of *Corel Painter* will set you back around $200, and the upgrades are about $99. *Krita* is free.

Similarly, brush packs for *Corel Painter* retail for about $30 each (and are generally not available for *Essentials*). I don't know if there's a corresponding version of sold *Krita* brushes. Both programs have many people giving brushes away for free and (outside of *Painter Essentials*), you generally have the ability to build any brush you might buy as long as you learn how to adjust brush parameters.

### Brush Types/Expression

This is where the *Corel Painter* lines pull ahead in my opinion. While the gap is narrowing, *Corel Painter* is still probably one of the best pieces of software for replicating the look of traditional artwork. Their Thick Paint, Real Oil, and Real Watercolor brushes look and act like traditional media. As best I can tell, the *Krita* brushes act more like regular digital art brushes with a few small tweaks.

I am honestly not certain how the *Krita* and *Corel Painter* particle brushes compare, although a fair amount of the premium brush packs from *Corel Painter* are variations on particle brushes that do some pretty amazing things. The default brushes are a bit more underwhelming, although again, you can replicate all of the premium brushes with the right tweaks.

### Stability

I have yet to see *Krita* crash when I was using it. *Corel Painter* has some persistent issues with application stability, with a running joke being that, much like *Star Trek* movies, the even-numbered ones are better.

### Overall

If you have a lot of spare cash, or can get a good deal (they apparently sell pretty cheap educational copies for students, and Humble Bundle has offered it at a great discount twice), *Corel Painter* is probably slightly superior overall. However, it does come at a premium.

Comment: Thanks. How do you find the painting process different between these two software? How or why do you find Corel Painter easier to use? For example, does it have a better selection tool?

Comment: Honestly, I don't use Krita enough to really comment on that. One minor problem I have with Krita is that it doesn't work well by default with dual monitors. I have my Wacom tablet set to only map to the primary monitor (I use the second one for videos and reference) and Krita interprets that as that my tablet should only map to half of the monitor, something Corel handles smoothly. I suspect there are settings I can change, but that is one mark against it not working automatically.